# CSS and JS Files are not loading in uiwebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

In my app, a website included in a folder. I tried to load it in webview using the following code:

```
self.wView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:NO];
    NSLog(@"%@",htmlFile);
    //NSData *pathData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile];
    //NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[htmlFile lastPathComponent] relativeToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[htmlFile stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] isDirectory:YES]];

    //(void)[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    [self.wView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]] ;
```

I get the file path in nslog.
But in my webview, css and js files are not loading.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Solution for this problem

Just select the option **Create Folder references for any added folders** while you are copying the Website folder into XCode